# Sales Force Exposing Custom Objects via REST API

Tags: rest, salesforce

I am new to sales force and I have a problem. I would like to manipulate (created,update,delete and select) data from my custom objects using the REST API.

I have managed to get the sample working and it is sending me the data for accounts. [Details](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API)

Now I would like to do the same for the Custom Object I have created.

I have tried this code but it is not working.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
GetMethod get = new GetMethod(instanceUrl + "/services/data/v22.0/sobjects/Employee__c/EC-1000");
get.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);
httpclient.executeMethod(get);
System.out.println("Status:" + get.getStatusCode());
System.out.println("Status Text:" + get.getStatusText());
```

Output is: 
Status:404
Status Text:Not Found

I created an object with name employee and ID EC-1000.

The above works for the default objects that is Account.

Answer (score 14):

It works exactly the same way, except you use your custom object's API name instead of the standard object name, e.g. If you have a custom object called Handsets, its api name will be Handsets__c, and you can do a POST to `/services/data/v22.0/sobjects/Handsets__c` to create a new one.

To access a particular record you need the 18 character record Id, just like for the account (or you need an externalId field setup).